# problem with splice() where it returns an array with a single element when i want to only single element

Tags: javascript

I have a function, which removes an element from an array and that element that returns, I put it in another array, the problem is splice() what it returns is an array with that element inside it, when I want only the element as in the case of a pop()

This is my code for splice and pop

```
$scope.quitarid = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.info.albumes.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.info.albumes[i].id === '3') {
            entrada_3 = $scope.info.albumes.splice(i, 1);
            console.log("entrada quitarid", entrada_3);
            $scope.segundatabla.push(entrada_3);
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log($scope.info.albumes);
};

$scope.quitarcd = function () {
    console.log($scope.info.albumes);
    entrada = $scope.info.albumes.pop();
    console.log($scope.info.albumes);
    console.log("entrada quitarcd", entrada);
    $scope.segundatabla.push(entrada);
    console.log($scope.segundatabla);
};
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNk3n.png)

[image]

Comment: With `splice()` returning an array, you can use `entrada_3[0]` to access the element you want.

Comment: Or `entrada_3 = $scope.info.albumes.splice(i, 1)[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

Given you know that splice in this instance will always return an array containing only the single item you want you could could simply access that item in the array and store it in entrada_3 instead. For example:

```
entrada_3 = $scope.info.albumes.splice(i, 1)[0];
```

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU <3
IT WORKS THX

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use spread syntax:

```
$scope.quitarid = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.info.albumes.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.info.albumes[i].id === '3') {
            entrada_3 = $scope.info.albumes.splice(i, 1);
            console.log("entrada quitarid", entrada_3);
            ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶s̶e̶g̶u̶n̶d̶a̶t̶a̶b̶l̶a̶.̶p̶u̶s̶h̶(̶e̶n̶t̶r̶a̶d̶a̶_̶3̶)̶;̶
            $scope.segundatabla.push(...entrada_3);
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log($scope.info.albumes);
};
```

It will de-construct the array and pass them as args to the `.push` method.

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)